# firefox top sites home page icon title

Tags: html, firefox, meta-tags, markup, web-development-server

does anyone know what meta tags firefox uses to show the "title" name on the topsites homepage?

I currently use:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="My App" />
<meta property="og:image" content="My Image URL">
<meta property="og:description" content="My site descriptionn">
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name">
```

which shows my icon properly but the title is the domain name that is in the url.  I would of expected the title to be "My title"

Any idea how i can set the title property properly?

many thanks

Comment: I think what you want is the [`<title>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) element, unless I misunderstood the **topsites homepage** for the **tab title**. Those `og` properties are mostly used for turning the page to an object for social graphing, like for **Facebook**, as stated [here](https://ogp.me/)

Comment: thanks I have the title set, unfortunately firefox ignores this for the naming of the title.   I'm suspecting they just grab the domain name atm.

Comment: How and where did you put the element?

Comment: I put the title element in the head as normal.